# Dividir nombre de una persona en nombres y apellidos con expresiones regulares y la función str_replace()

Tags: r, rstudio

Cordial saludo comunidad, estoy tratando de dividir por medio de expresiones regulares el nombre de personas en nombres (uno o si tiene dos) y apellidos (uno o si tiene dos). A continuación el código que he utilizado que es lo mejor que he podido hacer, pero sin lograr el resultado esperado:

```
library(tidyverse)

data <- data.frame(
  x = c('Darwin Miguel Galvis Reyes', 
        'Julian Luis Marquez Lopez',
        'Andrea Figueredo Perdomo',
        'Gonzalo Jimenez Parada',
        'Nathaly Ortiz'),
  y = c(31, 24, 32, 28, 22)
)

data <- data %>% 
  mutate(Nombre = str_replace(x, '^(\\w+)(\\s\\w+)?\\s\\w+\\s\\w+$', '\\1\\2'),
         apellido = str_replace(x, '^(\\w+)(\\s\\w+)?\\s(\\w+)(\\s\\w+)$', '\\3\\4'))
```

El resultado que deseo obtener es el siguiente:

| x | y | Nombre | Apellido |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Darwin Miguel Galvis Reyes | 31 | Darwin Miguel | Galvis Reyes |
| Julian Luis Marquez Lopez | 24 | Julian Luis | Marquez Lopez |
| Andrea Figueredo perdomo | 32 | Andrea | Figueredo Perdomo |
| Gonzalo Jimenez Parada | 28 | Gonzalo | Jimenez Parada |
| Nathaly Ortiz | 22 | Nathaly | Ortiz |

De antemano agradezco por cualquier ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

Te adjunto una solución que se me ocurrió estilo `tidyverse`, ya que mediante expresiones regulares no logre dar con el resultado

```
data %>%
  separate(
    col = x,into = c("Nombre_1", "Nombre_2", "Apellido_1", "Apellido_2"),sep = " ",remove = F
  ) %>% suppressWarnings() %>%
  mutate(
    Condicion = is.na(Nombre_2) + is.na(Apellido_1) + is.na(Apellido_2),
    Nombre = ifelse(Condicion == 0, paste(Nombre_1, Nombre_2), Nombre_1),
    apellido = case_when(
      Condicion == 1 ~ paste(Nombre_2, Apellido_1),
      Condicion == 2 ~ Nombre_2,
      TRUE ~ paste(Apellido_1, Apellido_2)
    )
  ) %>%
  select(x, y, Nombre, apellido)
```

1. Usar la función `separate()` para separar la variable x en 4 campos, a pesar de que sabemos que los clasificara mal
2. Crear la variable Condición para contar la cantidad de NA's que se nos generen en los 4 campos creados
3. Crear la variable Nombre a partir de la variable condición, que sera la concatenación del Nombre_1 y Nombre_2 o simplemente Nombre_1 si existe algún NA en la fila
4. Crear la variable apellido que va a depender de la condición de NA's, es decir,
   tomaremos lo que hay en Nombre_2 o en la concatenación de Nombre_2 y Apellido_1
5. Rescatar con `select()` los campos de interés

Observación: Esta solución esta directamente relacionada por como vengan los datos, pero creo que se pueden trabajar para llegar a esta misma estructura

**Ademas existe siempre el riesgo de clasificar un segundo nombre como un primer apellido, pero eso pasara tanto como para está solución o la solución con ReGex**

```
                           x  y        Nombre          apellido
1 Darwin Miguel Galvis Reyes 31 Darwin Miguel      Galvis Reyes
2  Julian Luis Marquez Lopez 24   Julian Luis     Marquez Lopez
3   Andrea Figueredo Perdomo 32        Andrea Figueredo Perdomo
4     Gonzalo Jimenez Parada 28       Gonzalo    Jimenez Parada
5              Nathaly Ortiz 22       Nathaly             Ortiz
```

Comment: creo que ayuda mucho pero cuando los segundos nombre tienen conectores pej: Maria del Rosario o Adilia de la Cruz. Creo que seria bueno un aporte de ejemplo con estos casos